# How to get tap gesture on a C4Image in a C4ScrollView

Tags: c4

I have several images loading in a scrollview.
I set up the C4ScrollView like this:

```
viewer = [C4ScrollView scrollView:CGRectMake(20, 30, 75, self.canvas.height - 50)];
viewer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(75, 1000);
[self.canvas addSubview:viewer];
```

and then I put the images in and add the tap gesture (in a for loop) like this:

```
C4Image* img = [C4Image imgWithUrl:imgUrl];    
[viewer addImage:img];
img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[img addGesture:TAP name:@"tap" action:@"tapped"];
[viewer listenFor:@"tapped" fromObject:img andRunMethod:@"imgTap:"];
```

then I have a method called imgTap like this:

```
-(void)imgTap:(NSNotification *)notification {
    C4Image *img = (C4Image *)notification.object;
    C4Log(@"image tapped");
}
```

But imgTap: method never gets called...
Am I doing something wrong? Or do I have to do something differently in order to get the C4Image to recognize the gesture?

Comment: do you specifically need the tap gesture? if not, using `touchesBegan` might fulfill what you need.

Comment: TouchesBegan fulfilled me in the end.  How would one go about using the tap gesture though? Is it possible? (just worried about touchesBegan intercepting a pan on the scrollview)

Comment: This is actually a bug. I filed it here: https://github.com/C4Framework/C4iOS/issues/112 . The C4Object class doesn't properly respond to `listenFor` from messages like `swipedUp`, `tapped` etc...